# Why are these not the same? And why isn't `type.GetType() is Test` true in C#?

Tags: c#

```
public class Test { }
public class InheritTest : Test { }

private void Main(string[] args)
{
   var test        = new Test();
   var inheritTest = new InheritTest();

   Console.WriteLine($"{test.GetType() is Test}");               // False
   Console.WriteLine($"{inheritTest.GetType() is InheritTest}"); // False
}
```

`GetType` is the actual instance.
But why isn't `type.GetType() is Test` true?

Comment: GetType() returns a new object of type System.Type.  It never matches Test.  Consider that you might have meant to use the `typeof` operator or Type.IsAssignableFrom() or simply `type is Test`, hard to tell,

Comment: Do note that the variable name is *very* misleading.  Strongly favor writing `Test obj = new Test();` to get your brain used to the idea that types and objects are not the same thing.

Comment: @HansPassant Thx Good answer!  Have good time! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[is (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

The is keyword evaluates type compatibility at runtime. It determines whether an **object instance** or the result of an expression can be converted to a specified type.

[Object.GetType Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the Type of the current instance.

Basically you don't need `GetType()`

**Update**

`type.GetType()` returns a `System.Type`

So along the lines of your original intentions you can imagine the following

```
// as you see, GetType() returns a type
Console.WriteLine($"{type.GetType() is Type}"); // True
```

[`typeof`](http://typeof%20(C#%20Reference)) returns a `Type` as well , so the following can be used to compare as well

> Used to obtain the System.Type object for a type

```
Console.WriteLine($"{type.GetType() == typeof(Test)}"); // True
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (or at least really explain to a novice) as to why `object.GetType() is SomeClass` doesn't work - - the fact that `System.Type` won't  be `is` (almost) anything

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 you are probably correct, ill update shortly